# Is a fiber optic connection considered a "wired" connection?

Tags: ethernet, ieee-802.11, layer1, cable, fiber

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.3

As Wikipedia says, 802.3 is for ..."wired Ethernet". How can I name copper and fiber networks in one word to describe 802.3 standard and to distinguish from 802.11?

Comment: "wired" - Ethernet is always wired, copper or fiber.

Comment: But fiber is not wire, or?

Comment: You don't have to cal it "wire" if you don't want to.  But everyone else does.

Comment: Not literally, but it's the same. Use "cable" if you want to make a difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I name copper and fiber networks in one word to describe 802.3
>   standard and to distinguish from 802.11?

IEEE 802.3 is ethernet, while IEEE 802.11 is Wi-Fi. They are distinct LAN protocols at both the physical and data-link layers. You simply distinguish them by their names. Ethernet is going to be on a wired medium, and Wi-Fi is going to be wireless. Each also uses a different frame format.

Comment: IEEE 802.3 is Ethernet, while IEEE 802.11 is Wi-Fi or wireless Ethernet

Comment: @nufuniliza, Wi-Fi is _not_ wireless ethernet. It does not use any physical or data-link protocols as defined by the ethernet standards. There is nothing resembling ethernet in Wi-Fi. It is actually ignorance and depending on marketing materials for your knowledge that causes people to think Wi-Fi is wireless ethernet.